# Can't find the modifiers wrench

Tags: modifiers

I am a newbie, and I'm following a tutorial, but I can't see the blue wrench showing up to add modifiers to the cube I have selected.
[image: workspace]

Answer (score 5):

Things show up in the properties editor based on what you have selected.

Notice that the outline around your cube is red, rather than orange.  That means it is one of multiple selected objects, and it is not the active object.  The active object, probably the camera, must be one that doesn't accept modifiers, so there will be no wrench action.

To fix your problem,

- Type <kbd>ALT</kbd>–<kbd>A</kbd> to deselect everything.
- Left click on the cube.

The wrench should show back up.

Comment: The active object can be `None` (which looks like this case, no object name in info, no object / data etc tabs) _eg_ after a delete.